# Objective-c NSArray with values from another class

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am trying to create a table view in my view based application but I am facing a problem

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"iPod",forecast.desc,nil];
NSLog(@"this is the forecast routeNo = %@", forecast.desc);
```

As you can see this is the array that shows the values in the table, the result of this code is iPod (only), "forecast.desc" doesn't show anything knowing that forecast is an instance of another class and "desc" is a string in that class

and just to make sure forecast.desc shows the correct information in the log but in the table as if doesn't exist can anyone see where is the problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Does the `NSLog` call output the value of `forecast.desc`?

Comment: Try `[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"iPod", [NSString stringWithString:forecast.desc], nil];`

Comment: yes NSLog output the value of forecast.desc, 

Simon, tried that before application crashes

Comment: Is `forecast.desc` a string? What is the output `NSLog` displays? I mean what is the actual string of `forecast.desc` contains?

Comment: @Simon: this is the output  "Altavista - Gatinue" which is a String as you can see

Comment: @bhappy: Alright.. Just to make myself clear, Does your table show two cells with the first cell containing the text @"iPod" and the second cell with an empty string/space? or, the table contains only one row? what value you are returning from `numberOfRowsInSection` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"iPod", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",forecast.desc], nil];
```

Comment: Thx man now am one step closer, it shows a null I have to figure that out, but now at least I know where is the problem

Answer (score 0):

@bhappy the result of array variable is @"iPod" only means that forecast.desc has nil value.

So try to debug the code using single stepping and check what is the value of desc at the time of initializing the array.

And one more thing if desc is a member variable of class forecast than did you set the property for it, if not then forecast.desc wont work. You should check that first.

Comment: Alright you have a good point there, I did what you mentioned apparently stopping at the NSArray line forecast will show an address but forecast.desc will show "out of scope" so I can't see the value unless am not doing it right 

and still showing output in the NSLog

Comment: so that it means you have not set the property of desc and you trying to access the object in another class or you dont have any value inside and still trying to access it and it will give you EXC_BAD_ACCESS. so which one is it.

Comment: if you did not set the property (i m assuming you didnt) so you should write the getter and setter methods for that object

Comment: Yes I do have a property in the class that forecast is pointing to if thats what you mean "@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *desc;"

Comment: did you alloc and init desc variable in the class were you are using it.  or you are doing stringWithFormat:

Comment: can you post the code when you are adding value in desc variable in that class

Comment: No i didn't can you explain why I need it and give me an example

Comment: This is the how I define forecast 

WeatherForecast *foreXX = [[WeatherForecast alloc] init];
[foreXX queryService:@"weather" withParent:self];
forecast=foreXX;

and the using desc just by calling forecast.desc

Comment: @Robin: Thank you man you are very helpful but now I figured from "Navaneethan" answer that forecast.desc for some reason shows null I guess I have to figure that out